# Unable to hit Web API 2 controller in MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am unable to hit API that I have written in MVC Project using ASP.Net Web API 2 controller.

[image]

`localhost:57323/api/billpayment/getbillers/10` works but `localhost:57323/api/billpayment/getbillers` doesn't work.

**WebAPI.config**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

Comment: By `doesn't works` what do you mean? you get 404? 500?

Comment: @trailmax getting 404

Comment: Do you have any other `GetBillers` methods?

Comment: @Liam No there are no other GetBillers method

Comment: I think you dont need overload in web api ,as id is already set as optional the in `WebApiConfig`.

Comment: @Neel I wrote single GetBiilers method with no parameter it doesn't works but Single GetBillers with Parameter works fine

Comment: What happens if you remove the first method with no parameter?

Comment: try to hide `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` from global.asax and then test once

Comment: @Neel 2nd method(with parameter) always works either I write 1st or not

Comment: @Nkosi It worked. I put GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); beforeRouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing route conflicts because of how the routes are configured.

Web API routes need to be added to the route table before standard MVC routes.

Update

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
    protected void Application_Start() {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); //<-- This MUST come before
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); //<-- THIS to avoid conflicts
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);        
    }
}
```